# Why is this TextView showing up on both of my TabPages? It should only be on the first

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs, android-tabhost

I have a `TextView` that is only supposed to show up on the first `TabPage` (which contains the `ScrollView`), but for some reason it shows up on both of my `TabPages`, whereas the TableLayout only shows up in the first TabPage like it should.  I have no idea why...here is my XML file:  The `TextView` in question is the 'primaryInfo' in the ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Primary Info"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/piTextView"
                        android:background="#595959"/>

                    <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/specsTab"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/photosTab">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/thumbnailGallery"
                    android:id="@+id/selectedPhoto"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageProgressLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                        android:indeterminate="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android_layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android_layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/galleryProgress"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/loadingTextView"
                        android:text="Loading images..."
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="13sp"/>           
                </LinearLayout>

                <Gallery
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnailGallery"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/galleryProgress"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

*edit*

Tab setup code:

```
    public void tabSetup()
{
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("Specs");
    tv1.setHeight(50);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText("Photos");
    tv2.setHeight(50);

    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Specs");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.specsTab);
    spec1.setIndicator("Specs");

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    spec2.setIndicator("Photos");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.photosTab);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
}
```

Comment: You know I thought about it more, I'm not really following your layout if you don't start new activities for each tab, how do you manage "tabs" then? How are tabs added to your tab host? More code is needed to understand how you are managing tabs if you don't use the built in functionality.

Comment: I added the code used to set up the tabs

Comment: Oh crap, I think I figured it out...one sec - I have changed the layout since I originally wrote that code.  I totally forgot about setContent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that when I  changed the layout, I forgot to change the View that I passed into the `setContent` method since the top level view for that tab page changed.  Here is what it was before I changed the layout (and it worked originally):

```
TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Specs");
spec1.setContent(R.id.specsTab);
spec1.setIndicator("Specs");
```

and this is what it needed to be with the current layout that I posted above:

```
TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Specs");
spec1.setContent(R.id.scrollView);
spec1.setIndicator("Specs");
```

Problem solved.  Credit to Jack for getting me to post the code since that is when I finally noticed it ;)